# Manage configuration files packaged in python modules

Tags: python, package, configuration-files

What's the proper way to manage configuration files that are embedded in a python module.

I have a python module (e.g. my_py_logger) that does a certain task (i.e. centralized logging). It's meant to be used by other python applications developed by the team. Once it is imported in a python application (e.g. my_py_app_a), developers are able to call a method in the logging module that init's the logging module. This method reads a config file. That config file is inside the my_py_logger package.

When I call this method from another package, python is not able to find the config file because the root folder has changed from my_py_logger's root source folder to my_py_app_a's root source folder.

`my_py_logger
    __init__.py
    config/
        default.conf
    init_logger.py`

`my_py_app_a
    __init__.py
    app.py`

I tried to use `importlib.import_module(__name__)` in the my_py_logger module to get the absolute path of the main file in my_py_logger, so I can technically extract the parent directory from that string/path and concatenate "../config/default.conf" but this feels like a poor solution. I'm sure there is a better way to handle this situation. Maybe putting this as a config file is not the right solution, but I'm sure I'm not the first guy to try this in python.

What would be the correct solution?

Comment: What about creating `~/.my_py_logger/default.conf` (if it doesn't exist) at logger init? This would allow a default config file per user.

Comment: This doesn't meet my requirements as I would need to ship default.conf separately with the module. And if it is missing, I would need to package a default.conf in the module which brings us to the original question, how do you refer a .conf file packaged in a module A when module A is imported in module B?

Comment: Well, you don't need to ship it separately from your module, just copy it from `init_logger.py` using something like `pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.joinpath('config', 'default.conf')`.
Anyway, storing and modifying the config file inplace inside you module structure, from external modules, does not seems to be a good idea.

Comment: How could this be done with storing a conf file? What's the norm for this in the python world?

Comment: There is no norm, and a few valid approaches actually (a quick [example](https://hackernoon.com/4-ways-to-manage-the-configuration-in-python-4623049e841b) for instance.)
You could also use a `~/.loggerrc` file, similar to `.bashrc` or `.condarc` approaches.

Comment: Thanks! You should post that as a reply to this question so I can select it as the correct answer.